# html button javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am wanting to have a button execute a function in my javascript file but it fails to do so when the button is clicked.

```js
function output() {
  if (form.inl.value == "1" && form.gate.value == "and" && form.inll.value == "0") {
    alert("output is 0")
  } else {
    if (form.inl.value == "1" && form.gate.value == "and" && form.inll.value == "1") {
      alert("output is 1")
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="inl">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
</select>
<select id="gate">
  <option value="and">and</option>
  <option value="or">or</option>
  <option value="not">not</option>
</select>
<select id="inll">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
</select>
<input id="out" type="button" value="output" onclick="output();">
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have to use onclick without ";" -> onclick="output()"

Comment: Where is your form?

Comment: What do you mean by *it fails* ? You are trying to call `form.inl` - what is `form` ?

Comment: The function `output()` is called, but it uses a `form` that isn't defined.

Try to use:

    `function output(){
        alert("output is 0")
    }` to check that it works for the moment.

Comment: @Roman Not true at all

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
function output(){
  var inl = document.getElementById('inl').value;
  var ln1 = document.getElementById('inll').value;
  var gate = document.getElementById('gate').value;
  if((inl == "1" && gate == "or" && ln1 == "0") || (inl == "0" && gate == "or" && ln1 == "1") || (inl == "1" && gate == "and" && ln1 == "1") || (inl == "1" && gate == "or" && ln1 == "1")){
      alert("output is 1")
  }
  else{
    alert("output is 0")
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="inl">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
</select>
<select id="gate">
  <option value="and">and</option>
  <option value="or">or</option>
  <option value="not">not</option>
</select>
<select id="inll">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
</select>
<input id="out" type="button" value="output" onclick="output();"></body>
```

Comment: An explanation about your code and what's different from the OP's would be useful

Comment: I am wanting to create a function calculator to tell the outputs for integrated circuits. For example, if I had 0 and 1 as the input (and being the gate type) I would get an output of 0.

Comment: Hi James, try the snippet now and let me know whether it is working as expected or not.

Comment: Hi James, may I know what causes you to unaccept my answer? Some explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works, you were trying to take value from elements that aren't present in your code.

JQuery approach:

```js
function output(){
if($("#inl")[0].value == "1" && $("#gate")[0].value == "and" && $("#inll")[0].value == "0"){
    alert("output is 0")

}
else{
if($("#inl")[0].value == "1" && $("#gate")[0].value == "and" && $("#inll")[0].value == "1"){
        alert("output is 1")
    }
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="inl">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
    </select>
    <select id="gate">
        <option value="and">and</option>
        <option value="or">or</option>
        <option value="not">not</option>
    </select>
    <select id="inll">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
    </select>
    <input id="out" type="button" value="output" onclick="output();"></body>
```

Javascript approach:

```js
function output(){
if(document.getElementById("inl").value == "1" && document.getElementById("gate").value == "and" && document.getElementById("inll").value == "0"){
    alert("output is 0")

}
else{
if(document.getElementById("inl").value == "1" && document.getElementById("gate").value == "and" && document.getElementById("inll").value == "1"){
        alert("output is 1")
    }
}
}
```

```html
<select id="inl">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
    </select>
    <select id="gate">
        <option value="and">and</option>
        <option value="or">or</option>
        <option value="not">not</option>
    </select>
    <select id="inll">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
    </select>
    <input id="out" type="button" value="output" onclick="output();"></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
function output(){
if(form.elements["inl"].value == "1" && form.elements["gate"].value == "and" && form.elements["inll"].value == "0"){
    alert("output is 0")

}
else{
if(form.elements["inll"].value == "1" && form.elements["gate"].value == "and" && form.elements["inll"].value == "1"){
        alert("output is 1")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. where is the form tag here.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the form by name. I would grab the fields by names and parse them as integers.

Then perform native calculations.

```js
function output() {
  let form  = document.forms['my-logic-form'],
      left  = parseInt(form.inl.value, 10),
      op    = form.gate.value,
      right = parseInt(form.inll.value, 10);
  
  alert('Output is: ' + doCalculation(op, left, right));
}

function doCalculation(op, left, right) {
  switch (op) {
    case 'and' : return left && right;
    case 'or'  : return left || right;
    case 'not' : return !left;         // Unary (right is ignored) 
    default    : return -1;            // Undefined operation
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="my-logic-form">
  <select name="inl">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
  </select>
  <select name="gate">
    <option value="and">and</option>
    <option value="or">or</option>
    <option value="not">not</option>
  </select>
  <select name="inll">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
  </select>
  <input name="out" type="button" value="output" onclick="output();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem may occurred due to browser:

Solutions are :

1: Rename "output()" function to any like "output1()"

2: Replace onclick="output();" to onclick="return output();"

3: You can use Debugger; and check whether your function is called or not.
   it is like checkpoint so you can check flow of your code after pressing ctrl+shift+i and then F10 to execute line by line..

eg.

```
function output() {
    debugger;
  if (form.inl.value == "1" && form.gate.value == "and" && form.inll.value == "0") {
    debugger;
    alert("output is 0")
  } else {
    debugger;
    if (form.inl.value == "1" && form.gate.value == "and" && form.inll.value == "1") {
      alert("output is 1")
    }
  }
}
```

One from this solutions is definitely useful to you. 
Thank you :)